# awk help for printing from a particular column till the end

Tags: awk

I have a file like this

```
gene    -   chr7    55675   55676   100 100
gene    -   chr7    55678   55679   100 100
gene    -   chr7    55683   55686   NP  100
```

The file is tab separated.

I want to change the file such that column 5 should be at column 4 and column 4 at column 5 and after that print all the columns as it is. I am showing you only 2 columns after 5th column, but there can be many more.

I tried `cut -f 1,2,3,5,4,6-` but it does not work.

I would prefer an awk solution for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To swap fields 4 and 5:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '{a=$4; $4=$5; $5=a;} 1' OFS='\t' file
gene    -       chr7    55676   55675   100     100
gene    -       chr7    55679   55678   100     100
gene    -       chr7    55686   55683   NP      100
```

How it works:

- `-F'\t'`

  This sets the field separator on input to a tab.
- `a=$4; $4=$5; $5=a`

  This swaps the fourth and fifth fields.
- `1`

  This is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-line.
- `OFS='\t'`

  This tells awk to use a tab as the field separator on output.

#### Leaving the header unchanged

To swap the fields on all lines except the first:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' 'NR>1{a=$4; $4=$5; $5=a;} 1' file
```

`NR` is the line number.   The `NR>1` placed before the swap commands is a condition.  The swap commands will be performed only if the condition is true.

#### Alternate style

Some stylists recommend that the assignment to OFS be before the code:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '{a=$4; $4=$5; $5=a;} 1' file
```

Comment: That works, thanks. Can you tell me how to print the first line which is the header as it is and start the above calculation from 2nd line onwards?

Comment: @user3138373 See update for code that leaves the header unchanged.